# Getting `undefined` value even after attaching socket to `ctx` in `beforeCall()` hook in moleculer.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, moleculer

I am using moleculerjs to handle microservices on the backend, and with one of the front-end applications I am handling the communication over sockets. To do that I am using `moleculer.io`. The problem I'm running into is that, even though I am attaching the socket to `ctx` in the `onBeforeCall()` hook, the socket is not there when I console.log `ctx` in the controller function.

My gateway looks like this (notice the socket is being added to the `ctx` object in the `onBeforeCall()` hook:

```
const SocketIOService = require("moleculer-io");

module.exports = {
  name: 'oas',
  mixins: [SocketIOService],

  settings: {
    port: 5000,
    io: {
      namespaces: {
        '/': {
          events: {
            'call': {
              aliases: {
                'auth.register': 'oas.controllers.auth.register'
              },
              whitelist: [
                '**',
              ],
              onBeforeCall: async function(ctx, socket, action, params, callOptions) { // before hook
                console.log('socket: ', socket); // This exists here
                ctx.socket = socket; // Here I attach the socket to the ctx object
              },
              onAfterCall: async function(ctx, socket, res) { // after hook
                // console.log('after hook', res)
                // res: The response data.
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    events: {},

    actions: {}
  }
};
```

And my auth.service looks like this - notice the `register()` function that tries to access `ctx.socket`:

```
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {import('moleculer').Context} Context Moleculer's Context
 */

module.exports = {
    name: "oas.controllers.auth",

    /**
     * Settings
     */
    settings: {

    },

    /**
     * Dependencies
     */
    dependencies: [],

    /**
     * Actions
     */
    actions: {
    async register(ctx) {
      console.log('ctx.socket: ', ctx.socket); // This is undefined

      // Other code...
    },

    /**
     * Events
     */
    events: {

    },

    /**
     * Methods
     */
    methods: {

    },

    /**
     * Service created lifecycle event handler
     */
    created() {

    },

    /**
     * Service started lifecycle event handler
     */
    async started() {

    },

    /**
     * Service stopped lifecycle event handler
     */
    async stopped() {

    }
};
```

Here in the `register()` function that gets called, `ctx.socket` is `undefined`. What am I missing here? I assume that `onBeforeCall()` is designed to be used for exactly this kind of purpose, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Is there a different way I should or could approach this to ensure the socket is available in the called function? And just to clarify, the socket is available in the `onBeforeCall()` hook. I need to figure out how to make it available down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a way to do this. Instead of attaching the socket to `ctx` directly, which as @Icebob pointed out, you can't do, I was able to attach it `ctx.meta`, like so:

```
onBeforeCall: async function(ctx, socket, action, params, callOptions) { // before hook
  ctx.meta.socket = socket;
},
```

By doing this I was able to successfully access the socket in my `register()` function.

Comment: Hi Guys, I will let  you know, if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can't put anything to the `ctx`. The ServiceBroker will serialize & transfer only the `ctx.params` and `ctx.meta` properties. But you can't put the socket into them because the Socket object what you like is not serializable, so you can't access it in remote services. It can work in a monolith project, not in a microservices project.